# Limiting Trig Function Return Values Python

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I'm making a game in python that involves quite a bit of trig.  I'm trying to optimize it to reduce lag as much as possible, and I think that it would help to have lower precision in the trig functions.  For example, math.sin(pi/3) returns something like 0.86602540378443864676372317075294.  Doing more operations on this means that the computer has to do a lot of unnecessary number crunching, and I really only need 2 or 3 decimal places of precision (like 0.866).  For context, here is the code that uses trig:

```
    xRel = x-camX
    yRel = y-camY
    zRel = z-camZ

    yp = yRel * math.cos(math.radians(pitch)) 
    zp = yRel * math.sin(math.radians(pitch))

    hy = math.sqrt(xRel*xRel+zRel*zRel) * mult(zRel)
    if zRel == 0:
        thetaYaw = 1.5708
    else:
         thetaYaw = math.atan(xRel/zRel) + math.radians(yaw)
    a = hy * math.cos(thetaYaw)
    thetaPitch = math.radians(pitch) + 1.5708

    xRel = round(hy * math.sin(thetaYaw), 3)
    yRel = round(a * math.cos(thetaPitch) + yp, 3)
    zRel = round(a * math.sin(thetaPitch) + zp, 3)
```

These calculations are performed for each entity at every program cycle.

I've tried using the round() method after calculating the ratio, but this only makes the lag worse, probably because of the extra steps the code has to run.  Is there a way/another math library where I can tell a trig function to stop calculating after a certain number of decimal places?

Comment: Not really clear what you're after. You could certainly implement your own Taylor series partial sum approximations of the trig functions, but there are almost definitely more appropriate optimizations you could make to your code. What are you performing these calculations on? Scalars? Matrices? How often are you calculating these results? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as your question is not particularly answerable (or useful for future web searches) at the moment.

Comment: How is this code being run? Are you running these calculations on lots of data? If so, have you looked into using numpy?